# Laurent series with $z_{0} = i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, complex-integration, laurent-series

I am trying to find the Laurent series of $$f(z) =\frac{1}{1-z^2}$$

with centre $z_{0} = i$.
However, I don't know how to calculate this as the centre is different from the poles, which are $$z =\pm 1 $$

I also need to find the regions of convergence.

Comment: $f(z)=a/(z-b)+c/(z-d) $ and $1/(z-b)=\frac{-1/(b-i)}{1-(z-i)/(b-i)}$

Comment: Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* Laurent series of $f$ centered at $i$. There is the Laurent series which converges to $f(z)$ when $|z-i|<\sqrt2$ and there is the Laurent series which converges to $f(z)$ when $|z-i|>\sqrt2$

Comment: @AnotherUser how did you get $$|z-i|<\sqrt[]{2}$$

Comment: It's the distance from $i$ to $\pm1$.

Comment: makes sense! thank you